# unable to push changes to mercurial repo using tortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

In changeset it shows that I have 12 changes to be pushed but when I click push to mercurial repo it says "no outgoing changesets to URL". this is my first attempt at using TortoiseHg for code push. please assist.

Comment: Were those changes committed?

Comment: yes, I have committed the changes, also had some merge issue which I resolved.

Comment: you must to show real sample (screenshots?). There it shows 12 changesets, there (after which actions) it can push nothing?

Comment: Yeah it shows the list of files and then when I hit ush it says "pushing changesets to URL" and after like 10-15 seconds it fails. saying "No outgoing changesets to URL". Am trying to make sure that my account has write permission I hope that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with description, I had an extra space in the beginning of the description while committing code to my local web server. which prevented it from being pushed to global repo.